# Car Class (first time with classes)

Tags: c++, function, class, header

For an assignment I needed to use a class named car and have it display the make and model, and also have the speed increase by 5 when you use accelerate and decrease by 5 when you brake. My teacher helped me along the way but when I got to the end I couldn't get it to run. Could someone correct me and tell my why it's wrong?

Imp---------

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void accelerate()
{ 
    int speed;
    speed = speed + 5;
}

void brake()
{
    int speed;
    speed = speed - 5;
}
```

---

Header

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class car
{
public:
    car(int getYear, string getMake);
    void accelerate();
    void brake();

private:
    int year;
    string make;
    int speed;
};
```

---

CarClass.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include "CarClass.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    car.(2013,"Kia")
    car.accelerate()
    car.brake()
}
```

Comment: None of the lines in your `main()` method have `;` on the end.  That won't even build!  Also, seeing as this is homework just a hint: did you know that you can declare a local variable in a class's member method that has the same name as one of the class's attributes?  And if you did, then within said method you would effectively hide the member attribute.

Comment: What does the compiler tell you? there are so many things wrong with this that you're not going to get an answer unless you can be more specific.

Comment: Well the complier was telling me I had unresolved external symbols, and looked up what that meant and figured it was something with my functions, as I still struggle with them.

Answer (score 3):

This code has two mistakes

```
void accelerate()
{ int speed;


    speed = speed + 5;

}
```

it should be

```
void car::accelerate()
{
    speed = speed + 5;
}
```

Same problem for brake. You use the `car::` notation to indicate that these functions are *methods* of the class `car`.

You missed out the constructor definition, which is used to create `car` objects.

```
car::car(int getYear, string getMake)
{
    year = getYear;
    make = getMake;
    speed = 0;
}
```

This should go in the same file as car::accelerate and car::brake.

This code is terribly wrong

```
car.(2013,"Kia")
car.accelerate()
car.brake()
```

I think you meant this

```
car mycar(2013,"Kia");
mycar.accelerate();
mycar.brake();
```

Now the code will build and run but it's still not going to do anything. I'm not sure what you are expecting it to do, so I can't really help with that.

If your teacher can't help you then perhaps you should read a book on C++. Programming is very unforgiving, if you don't get it *exactly* right it's usually *completely* wrong. You can't bluff your way in this, you have to get some solid knowledge from somewhere.

Comment: The constructor should use an initialization list.

Comment: @juanchopanza The OP has a lot to learn, I'm trying to introduce as little as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure teaching them a bad practice they will have to unlearn at the first opportunity is such a good idea.

Comment: OKay, thanks a lot. I forgot the other half, and now I have it.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your accelerate() and brake() functions have a speed variable defined in function scope. You can change your code to this:

```
void car::accelerate()
{ 
    speed += 5;
}



void car::brake()
{  
    speed -= 5;
}
```

In order to use the class, you need to declare it like so:

```
Car car = new Car(2013,"Kia");
```

Also make sure there are semi colons ";" at the end of your function prototypes and function calls so it will be able to compile.

Comment: That initialization is not legal C++.

Comment: Use Car car = Car(2013,"Kia"); or Car* car = new Car(2013,"Kia");

Comment: @juanchopanza Oh yeah, I was thinking C# because I'm coding in C# right now lol. My bad.

Comment: @aj.toulan Just `car x(2013, "Kia");` will do.

Comment: The class is called `car` not `Car`, let's not confuse the OP more than necessary.